# Sorting base64 encoded list of apps & icons

Tags: android, list, sorting, base64

I am using an Android app that returns an html file containing a list of user-selected app names, alongside their app launch icons, from installed Android apps on a phone. The app names are clickable links to that app's Play Store page.

The app output list is not sorted alphabetically.
The output code contains icon images encoded in base64 but it doesn't use the url & filename safe form of encoding (base64url).

From my understanding, this makes sorting the output (which is not a table) very involved, whether accomplished within the app or working within the output file.

I would appreciate any description of the series of steps necessary to accomplish this by working within the output file, so that I can sort my lists.

I am very curious as to why this very comprehensive, well performing app doesn't offer to sort the output, unless the code it would need rwould require a language not compatible with the rest of the programming.

Comment: Post the html file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.